# Can't save the data using wbragancia widget yii2 for more than one dynamic form in single view

Tags: yii2

I am new in yii2 and i am using wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform widget in my view. My question is that I have to use more than two dynamic form in a single view. For single dynamic widget it works fine while saving from controller but others are saving just the last data of dynamic widget, while inspecting the post data in network array index for others except first dynamic form are not increasing (there index is only zero). Would you please suggest how should I have to do. How can I use multiple dynamic-form widget in single view. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem must be in your view. You should ensure that each control has a unique name and then loop through the post variables in the controller.

```
<?= $form->field($modelx, "[{$i}]MyVariableName", ['labelOptions' => ['label' => false]])->textInput(['name' =>'myClassNameHere'."{$block}[$i][MyVariableName]"]) ?>
```

See the 'name' option in the code above. It gives a unique name to each field. Here the $block variable is a unique code I append to each widgetItem class in the DynamicFormWidget.

If I now look at my POST data, I see something like the following:

```
myClassNameHere0[0][MyVariableName]:1
myClassNameHere1[0][MyVariableName]:11
```

If this does not help - post a simply example that you cannot get working and I will have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you sifa..I had edited the properties of the widget then now it works fine.